# How to combine dataframes without losing data?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to combine two dataframes with a preference for leaving the left DataFrame's data over the right's:

I currently have:

```
(Pdb) pp question_struct
   QuestionID       RowID  MenuID  ColumnID SourceRowID  SourceColumnID  SourceVariationID
0   316926394  3029937752       0         0  3029937752               0                  0
1   316926394  3029937753       0         0  3029937753               0                  0
2   316926394  3029937754       0         0  3029937754               0                  0
3   316926394  3029937755       0         0  3029937755               0                  0
4   316926394  3029937756       0         0  3029937756               0                  0
5   316926394  3029937757       0         0  3029937757               0                  0

[6 rows x 7 columns]
(Pdb) pp df
  QuestionID       RowID ColumnID MenuID SourceRowID SourceColumnID  SourceVariationID  ResponseCount
0  316926394  3029937753        0      0  3029937753              0                  0              1

[1 rows x 8 columns]
(Pdb) df.combine_first(question_struct)
  ColumnID MenuID QuestionID  ResponseCount       RowID SourceColumnID SourceRowID  SourceVariationID
0        0      0  316926394              1  3029937753              0  3029937753                  0
1        0      0  316926394            NaN  3029937753              0  3029937753                  0
2        0      0  316926394            NaN  3029937754              0  3029937754                  0
3        0      0  316926394            NaN  3029937755              0  3029937755                  0
4        0      0  316926394            NaN  3029937756              0  3029937756                  0
5        0      0  316926394            NaN  3029937757              0  3029937757                  0

[6 rows x 8 columns]
```

but it is losing the first row of question_struct 3029937752 even though it doesn't conflict with anything in df and duplicating 3029937753 which does conflict.

Comment: This would work if RowID were the index of these frames.

Answer (score 2):

[`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) is just matching the index, not the values (like a merge would), and updating the NaNs in these rows. If you had additional columns in `question_struct` or NaNs in `df` then these would be combined into the new DataFrame, since you don't it doesn't extract anything.

Here's an example to explain what's going on:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], index=[1, 2], columns=['A', 'C'])

In [13]: df1.combine_first(df2)
Out[13]:
   A   B   C
0  1   2 NaN
1  3   4   6
2  7 NaN   8
```

*See that the 5 is not included, because `df1` already has a value for row 1's column B.*

If we make the 3 an NaN first, then it'll use the 5:

```
In [14]: df1.iloc[1,0] = np.nan  # was a 3

In [15]: df1.combine_first(df2)
Out[15]:
   A   B   C
0  1   2 NaN
1  5   4   6
2  7 NaN   8
```

Comment: So whats the best solution here?  A merge?

Comment: @sontek it depends what you want to happen with discrepancies/differences in the data. If there both the same, use merge, if you want them to update in combine_first you have to index them with the unqiue index.